# I want to debug ruby files which are on Linux on my Windows laptop using RubyMine 2016.2

Tags: ruby, rubymine

My web application is built on Linux hence my automation Ruby code is also running on Linux machine. Currently for debugging I am using Putty.

All I want is to debug these Ruby files which are on Linux on my Windows laptop. How can I do that? I have installed RubyMine on my Windows laptop already.

Comment: FTP or SFTP the Ruby files from your Linux box to your Windows box and voila.

Comment: I think you should use remote debug. This article can help you: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/8.0/run-debug-configuration-ruby-remote-debug.html

Comment: @JonnyHenly Please, no. FTP is awful. `rsync` at the very least.

Comment: @tadman : ) I was just using SFTP so it was the first thing to come to mind.

Comment: @JonnyHenly The advantage of `rsync` is it will pick out files that have changed rather than force-dumping everything.

Comment: @tadman That's a good point, especially if OP wants to transfer the same files for debugging in the future.